Is there a better method and more efficient way to determine the type of triangle based on the coordinates of its three vertices?
list={{{-2, -7}, {3, 18}, {8, 17}}, {{-2, -7}, {8, 17}, {15, 
   0}}, {{-2, -7}, {8, 17}, {15, 10}}, {{-2, -7}, {8, 17}, {16, 
   5}}, {{-2, 17}, {3, -8}, {8, -7}}, {{-2, 17}, {3, 
   18}, {8, -7}}, {{-2, 17}, {8, -7}, {15, 0}}, {{-2, 
   17}, {8, -7}, {15, 10}}, {{-2, 17}, {8, -7}, {16, 5}}}

Given the coordinates of the three vertices of a triangle, how can one identify whether the triangle is an acute triangle, a right triangle, or an obtuse triangle based on these coordinates?
triangles = {{{-2, -7}, {3, 18}, {8, 17}}, {{-2, -7}, {8, 17}, {15, 0}}, {{-2, -7}, {8, 17}, {15, 10}}, {{-2, -7}, {8, 17}, {16, 5}}, {{-2, 17}, {3, -8}, {8, -7}}, {{-2, 17}, {3, 18}, {8, -7}}, {{-2, 17}, {8, -7}, {15, 0}}, {{-2, 17}, {8, -7}, {15, 10}}, {{-2, 17}, {8, -7}, {16, 5}}};

triangleType[triangle_] := Module[
{a, b, c, sides},
sides = Map[EuclideanDistance @@ # &, Partition[Flatten[triangle], 2]];
{a, b, c} = Sort[sides];
If[a^2 + b^2 == c^2, "Right triangle", If[a^2 + b^2 > c^2, "Acute triangle", "Obtuse triangle"]]]

triangleTypes = triangleType /@ triangles


Update:
according to Daniel Huber
triangles = Polygon[{{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}}]
PolygonAngle[triangles] // FullSimplify
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], triangles}]



Related.

What have you tried?

Then what's the question now?

Then what do you mean by "better"?

Then what do you mean by "to the point"?

RightTriangleQ is available at the Wolfram Function Repository.

Look up "PolygonAngle" in the help.

Try
Map[Sign[Cross[#[[2]] - #[[1]]] . (#[[3]] - #[[1]])] &, triangles]
(*{-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1}*)

Positive sign gives  counterclockwise orientation, negative sign clockwise orientation!
Or
Map[PositivelyOrientedPoints, triangles]
(*{False, False, False, False, True, False, True, True, True}*)


The code does what you say -- no problem there. But the question is not a  binary or true/false question about orientation. It's about the maximum angle and has three possible answers. The upvotes are inexplicable.

triangleType[tri : {Repeated[{_, _}, {3}]}] :=
  With[
    {maxangle = Max[PolygonAngle[Triangle[tri]]]},
    Which[
      maxangle < Pi/2, "acute",
      maxangle > Pi/2, "obtuse",
      True, "right"]];

triangleType /@ triangles
(* {"right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right"} *)

The argument pattern is more to communicate the expected form of the input rather than to actually protect against bad input.
